# why sometimes UI in my pages sometimes appears sometimes does not appear?

Tags: jsf, spring-security, primefaces, glassfish-3

i've little problem

why sometimes UI in page.jsf, appears sometimes does not appear... 
and i didn't get any error in there

i'm using :

netbeans 6.9.1 
JSF 2.0 
primefaces 3.1.1 
springframework 3.0.2 
glassfish server 3.0

i means : i can't load my primefaces, javascript and css in jsf.page 
**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/assets/previews/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/assets/thumbs/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/design/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/pageAllNews/**" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/pageLogin/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/css/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/skins/tn3/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/templates/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/userPage/**" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')"/>

    <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                default-target-url="/userPage/home.jsf"
                login-page="/userPage/home.jsf"
                authentication-failure-url="/userPage/test.jsf"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/userPage/home.jsf"/>
    <remember-me />

</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</b:beans>
```

thx, need your help & suggest 
agungdmt

Comment: This is a too broad question. Please isolate the problem into the smallest possible piece of code which we can basically copy'n'paste'n'run into a blank playground project to see it ourselves so that we can point out the mistake.

Comment: hii balusC, sorry about that, please see update

Comment: Sorry, Spring is beyond me. I won't be surprised if the problem is in Spring config though. You at least need to make sure that `/javax.faces.resource/*` requests are been passed through. They are been used by `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:graphicImage>`.

Comment: ok thx for suggest BalusC...:D

Answer (score 0):

i can solve it, just remote the sign [*] 
from

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

to

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and it's works

Comment: This way the filter runs only when the default servlet runs and thus not when any other servlet like `FacesServlet` runs. Isn't your security on JSF pages disabled this way?